# Moving around a summation

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

Suppose we have the following:

$$\min_j\sum_i A_{ij}$$

Where $A$ is a matrix. Note this produces the minimum column sum of $A$. Is this equal to

$$\sum_i\min_j A_{ij}$$

I tested it with the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$

and both return the solution 4. Is this statement true?

Comment: What happens if you try $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2 \\ 4&3\end{pmatrix}$? (The moral of the story is: Try several examples.)

Comment: No.  Try $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0& \\ 56,789,823&128,932,104&10^{532}\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Um, For the matrix you list the minimum column sum is 4 but the sum of the column minimums is 3; not 4.

Comment: " (The moral of the story is: Try several examples.)" Can't argue with that but another moral is "think".  The minimum of the sums require all the terms of the matrix to be processed.  The sum of the minimums allows you to simply "throw away" all of the terms except one from each column.  The stuf you "throw away" can change everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&10^{532} \\ 0&128,932,104&0& \\ 56,789,823&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.